# How set thumbnails image of video player

Tags: swift, mpmovieplayer

I am new swift

I am creating video player, it's have background play facility but when i goes background or lock iPhone then play,pause,next,previous controls are there but thmbnails of video playing vide not set ...

if can i set thumbnail of video
like this[image]

can i set it if have any method to do it

thanks

Comment: What do you expect us to answer here. You have provided no details minus the fact you are using Swift

Comment: i want to set thumbnails of video which playing in app and app goes background or lock then image set like above image

Comment: updated description....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Swift 2, to create an image out of video use this code:

```
    var thumbImage: UIImage?
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    let asset = AVAsset(URL: fileURL)
    let assetImgGenerate = AVAssetImageGenerator(asset: asset)
    assetImgGenerate.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = true
    let time = CMTimeMake(asset.duration.value / 3, asset.duration.timescale)
    if let cgImage = try? assetImgGenerate.copyCGImageAtTime(time, actualTime: nil) {
        thumbnailImage = UIImage(CGImage: cgImage)
    }
```

now you have image. To make it cover you must use MPNowPlayingInfo. Add this piece of code when you update info:

```
    // works to do to initialise now playing info
    if let artwork = thumbImage {
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(image: artwork)
    } else {
        nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = nil
    }
    MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
```

Comment: thnx works like charm!!!!!

Comment: Hey, don't know why but its taking 10-15 secs to display the image...

Comment: @vivektakrani I don't know the architecture of you app but maybe due to loading over internet or having many simultaneous thread.